# How do I change colouring of comments using algorithmicx?

Tags: comments, algorithmicx

I am using the `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` packages, whilst wrapping my algorithms around `algorithm` and `algorithmic` blocks. **I would like to change the colour or formatting of my comments (`\Comment{...}`) to make them more or less pronounced compared to standard code**, as often with narrow technical documents the comment and pseudocode may come close together and the comment may perhaps overflow to the next line, slightly hampering readability.

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just redefine the `\algorithmiccomment` command provided by algpseudocode. I usually use: `\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment[1]{\hfill$\triangleright$\textit{#1}}`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill$\triangleright$\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm with very important comments}
\begin{algorithmic}
\If {$i\geq maxval$}
    \State $i\gets 0$
\Else
    \If {$i+k\leq maxval$}
        \State $i\gets i+k$ \Comment{This is comment}
    \EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class for examples; it's not meant for this purpose.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. I managed to make my comments grey as a result. You are missing a close brace in your paragraph of text. `\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment[1]{\hfill$\triangleright$\textit{#1}}`

Answer (score 0):

The same problem can be solved with `algpseudocodex` [package](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algpseudocodex/algpseudocodex.pdf) (`commentColor` option).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please improve your answer by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and an image of the result.